# Advanced custom fields and thumbnail size (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

My client has a website which lists 3 thumbnails, this is great but I need to get a cropped version of the thumbnail rather than the default thumbnail. The thumbnail class is called "type-one".

```
<?php 
        $i = 0;
        //$query = new WP_Query( array('category_in' => array_merge(array('6'),$subcats)) );
        //$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=page&post_parent=35&posts_per_page=3' );
        $query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_parent' => 35,
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            'posts_per_page' => 3
            )
        );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ){
            while ( $query->have_posts() ){
                $query->the_post();
                $fields = get_fields();
                $i++;
    ?>
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
        <?php if( $fields['featured_image'] ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $fields['featured_image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fields['featured_image']['alt']; ?>" class="margin-bottom" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php echo $fields['introduction']; ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    } // while
    } // if have posts
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out the $fields array to see what you're working with. With Advanced Custom fields there is a 'sizes' array on image fields -

```
<?php echo $fields['featured_image']['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set post thumbnail size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) for Crop the image feature image

To be used in the current theme's *functions.php* file.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
```

**Note:** This function will not resize your existing featured images.

In your *functions.php*, paste one of these and adjust pixel width and height to your liking.

*Set the default Post Thumbnail size by resizing the image proportionally (that is, without distorting it):*

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50 ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, resize mode
```

*Set the default Post Thumbnail size by cropping the image (either from the sides, or from the top and bottom):*

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, crop mode
```

Hope this help you well!

Answer (score 1):

Place this in function.php ,

```
function yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['activated'] ) || $pagenow != 'themes.php' ) {
        return;
    }
    $catalog = array(
        'width'     => '400',   // px
        'height'    => '400',   // px
        'crop'      => 1        // true
    );
    $single = array(
        'width'     => '600',   // px
        'height'    => '600',   // px
        'crop'      => 1        // true
    );
    $thumbnail = array(
        'width'     => '120',   // px
        'height'    => '120',   // px
        'crop'      => 0        // false
    );
    // Image sizes
    update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );       // Product category thumbs
    update_option( 'shop_single_image_size', $single );         // Single product image
    update_option( 'shop_thumbnail_image_size', $thumbnail );   // Image gallery thumbs
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing code,
You can fix Thumbnail size from admin panel check this Post,

[Thumbnail size from admin panel](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/using-the-appropriate-product-image-dimensions/)